# SVN project in Eclipse with brown parts

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, svn, icons

I have a svn project in eclipse which **project icon has brown parts**.
Unfortunately I was not able to find any answer, why this project has a different icon compared to others.

Does anyone know whats the semantics of this icon?
Is it from svn, maven or eclipse?

I do not ask about the asterisk in the icon, but of the brown part above the asterisk.

[image: enter image description here]]

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem its the Jboss Fuse plug-in, is necessary to remove it from your installation.

**Help** -> **Eclipse Market** -> **Jboss Tools** -> **Change** -> **Remove Jboss Fuse checks**